# multiple resource directories for maven android build

Tags: android, maven, android-maven-plugin

when using android-maven-plugin, there is resourceDirectory parameter which allows you to configure resource directory. How to configure multiple resource directories?

The following is an example pom file, resourceDirectory can be configured for android-maven-plugin, but only one directory can be configured.
Is there a way to configure more than one resource directory?

I tried build-helper-maven-plugin. It does not help. http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
                <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
                <genDirectory>${project.basedir}/gen</genDirectory>
                <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
                <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>7</platform>
                </sdk>
            </configuration>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
```